# Visual Studio Web, I am trying to retrieve value from SQL, how do I check whether value is NULL?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

So I got `SQL` Table something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Payment
(
    paymentID CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    paymentName VARCHAR(20),
)

INSERT INTO Payment VALUES ('P1', NULL')
```

In `Visual Studio` side, whenever I try to access for example the `paymentID`
I would use something like

```
IF (reader["paymentID"].ToString() == "P1") then
    // do something
```

How can I check whether `paymentName` is NULL?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For null checking of string you can use

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["paymentName"]  as string);
```

Comment: Hi
I can't  write IF (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["paymentName"]  as string)